# AndroidX build issue with ProGuard

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx

**CLOSED**

We are trying to integrate android library (which is compiling android support library) in our project that has been migrated to androidX. And for unknown reason we are getting

```
can't find referenced method 'void addOnTabSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener)' in program class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```

while trying to get a **proguard** enabled build.

`gradle-wrapper: 4.8`

`gradle build tools : 3.2.0`

`compileSdkVersion 28`

**EDIT 9-Oct-2018**

For some reason, it was a proguard issue, proguard was showing wrong error, after we made some changes in our sourcecode, and forgot to add some classes to proguard, it changed the errors with the classes that we forgot to add. and after adding them everything went good.

Comment: Check logic https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Android/issues/123

Comment: Did you migrate to AndroidX, Are you sure it is migrated? Which dependencies you have in `build.gradle`? Please add more information + dependencies.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท it is the exact issue mentioned here  https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Android/issues/123

Comment: It looks like your last edit actually contains the *answer* to the problem.  In that case, the right action is to post an **answer** instead of editing.  Please roll back and post your solution as an answer (then we can vote on that as well as on your question, so it's good for your reputation points, too!)

Answer (score 18):

I think that you should tell to proguard to not obfuscate material classes.
But this is just a workaround, you have some other issue so try to fix it.

Try to add these lines in your **proguardrules.pro** file:

```
-keep class com.google.android.material.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.google.android.material.**
-dontnote com.google.android.material.**

-dontwarn androidx.**
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }
```

Then, in your **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw/master"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:ff9c89416cc1c8adf83d481a1e5fd515fcb893b9'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:your version'
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a warning that breaks the building, but when i add --dontwarn it builds normally but crashes when starting the activity that contains the interface

Comment: Full stacktrace can be found here https://github.com/Instabug/Instabug-Android/issues/123#issuecomment-424261311

Comment: Same thing, it didn't break the build, but once the activity that contains the class starts it crashes.

Comment: Keeping *everything* in `androidx` package is beyond overkill.

Comment: @tir38 do you know how to remove those folder's insde androidx which we are not using it .